# A complex function that is harmonic but not analytic

Tags: complex-analysis, examples-counterexamples, harmonic-functions, analyticity

Can someone give a simple example of a complex function that is harmonic but not analytic?

Thanks.

D.

Comment: Natural examples are $\mbox{Re}\;z, \mbox{Im}\; z, \bar{z}$...

Answer (score 15):

$x{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: You probably mean $z\mapsto\mathrm{Re}(z)$.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't resist the temptation of  a one- typographical-character answer :-) [But made it community wiki].

Comment: @girianshiido: yes.

Comment: Must be a [French](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/97032/) [thing](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383/)... :-)

Comment: @Martin: oui! (and thanks for the link to my predecessors-rivals: grrr...!)

Comment: Why didn't you add the links yourself, one wonders?