# Intersection of two simply connected sets in $\mathbb C$

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Suppose $E \subset \mathbb C$ is an open, simply connected set and the boundary $\partial E$ is not empty. Let $x \in \partial E$. Is it true: we can always find some open disk $D(x, r) = \{y \in \mathbb C: |y-x| < r\}$ such that the intersection $E \cap D(x, r)$ is simply connected? As discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173424/intersection-of-simply-connected-sets) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/469846/intersection-of-simply-connected-sets-ii), essentially we want to know whether there exists some $r$ such that $E \cap D(x, r)$ is path-connected?

---

As the example showed in the comment, this is not true. What sufficient condition would guarantee such open disk exists? For example, is path-connectedness of the boundary $\partial E$ sufficient?

Comment: Take an open square $(0,1)^2$ and delete the segments $\{(1/n;t):\text{ for }t\in[1/2,1)\}$, for $n=1,2,3,...$. Then look at $x=(0;2/3)$.

Comment: @LB_O: Thanks for your example. May I ask whether there is some sufficient condition to guarantee this? Does path-connectedness of the boundary suffice?

Comment: The boundary of that example is path-connected. Locally path-connected should do it, since then you can map the closure of $E$ to the closed unit disc by a continuous function that is conformal in the interior.

Comment: You can complete it to an answer and post it yourself. Find the source to the result I mentioned above. Maybe Ahlfors' book on complex analysis has it. I don't know. Show that the example is actually an example.

Comment: Assume E is regular open.

Comment: @WilliamElliot: Thanks. May I ask in the case ($E$ is regular open): would $E \cap D$ be regular open? I have seen counterexample to show union of regular open sets is not necessarily open, but the counterexample is about two open sets with empty intersection.

Comment: Yes, intersection of two regular open sets is regular open.  For regular open U, boundary U = boundary closure U.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The space between a circle of radius 2 centered at 0 and a
circle of radius 1 centered at 1 is simply connected, regular
open.  The point of tangency is a counter example.

Is the property you'd like, E is regular open with a
simply connected closure?  Here we are considering every
disk D.  If you want just one disk, then if E is bounded,
any disk containing E will suffice.

Comment: Forgive my lack of knowledge, I could not prove the statement assuming $E$ is regular open and has simply connected closure. Could you give more hints on this part? Thanks.

Comment: @iris2017.  Did you ignore the question mark?  Regular open, which got rid of some counter examples, did not get rid of all of them.  So I added another premise, that got rid of the new counfer example I presented.  Does it get rid of all of them?  I do not know.  Will the math muse inspire me again tonight?