# How to know whether an integral can be solved?

Tags: calculus, integration

I just wonder: How do you know whether an integral can be solved? For example, exponential integral can  not be derived to final result.

Comment: What does *final result* mean?

Answer (score 1):

You don't *solve* integrals, you *compute* them. The integral
$$
   \int_0^x \frac{e^t}{t}\, dt
$$
can be computed as any other integral. Only the result is not a function which you may find in every pocket calculator...

Comment: indefinte integrals are not computed but evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

Integrals are not solved, indefinite integrals are **evaluated**.
One may **compute** definite integrals.
The question you are trying to ask is this: "What integrals can be evaluated in terms of elementary or well known transcedental functions"

Example of transcedental functions : $\sin x , \ln x, e^x $ etc.

Comment: $Ei(x)$ is a well known transcendental function.

Comment: The distinction definite/indefinite integrals regarding evaluation/computation seems irrelevant since lots of indefinite integrals are equivalent to definite ones and vice versa.

Comment: @Did : yes that is correct, but I have not seen any examples of the two being interchanged in books, if I see some examples of them being interchanged in books written by native English speakers then I can agree.

Comment: Your procedures of agreement are a tad peculiar, to say the least... Since you do not mention *books written by native English speakers* in your post, my remark fully applies and you might want to reformulate your (at present misleading) post.

Comment: @Did : If you could adjust the misleading part any way you see fit please, Ill appreciate it. I agree with anything that I either can infer, deduce or see some examples of it around. PS : I did found this answer of yours awesome : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/74383#74383

Comment: Omit "definite" in the second sentence. (Thanks for the appreciation of the W answer.)

Comment: @Did : done, thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is no universal criterion, distinguishing which integrals can be computed in elementary functions. (Rational functions of the exponent.)