# Where is the mistake in this argument that $(\sqrt8)^{\sqrt 7} >(\sqrt7)^{\sqrt 8}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I posted an answer in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431461/prove-that-sqrt7-sqrt8-sqrt8-sqrt7) to prove that $(\sqrt8)^{\sqrt 7}<(\sqrt7)^{\sqrt 8}$

I started with

$$f(x)=\frac{\ln x}{x}$$

$$f'(x)=\frac{1-\ln x}{x^2}$$

$$f'(x)>0 : x\in)0,e($$  $$f'(x)<0 : x\in)e,+\infty($$

so $f(1/7)>f(1/8)$, hence $-8\ln 8<-7\ln7$

so

$$\begin{align}
8\ln 8 & > 7\ln7\\\\
0.5\cdot 8\ln 8 & >0.5\cdot 7\ln7\\\\
8\ln \sqrt8 & > 7\ln\sqrt7\\\\
\ln (\sqrt8)^{\sqrt 7}& >\ln(\sqrt7)^{\sqrt 8}\\\\
(\sqrt8)^{\sqrt 7} &>(\sqrt7)^{\sqrt 8}
\end{align}$$

but where is the mistake with my answer, because $(\sqrt8)^{\sqrt 7}<(\sqrt7)^{\sqrt 8}$?!

Comment: How did you go from the third to last step to the second to last step? I could see how you might arrive at $\sqrt(8)^{\frac{1}{7}} > \sqrt{7}^{\frac{1}{8}}$, which is true. But I don't see how your third to last step implies your second to last step.

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh: Just by the way, it is not correct to say "*Where is the wrong?*". You should use a word such as "*mistake*" or "*error*" instead of "*wrong*".

Comment: @AWertheim
but I know that if $g'(x)> 0$ for every $x\in D$ so if a>b and $a,b \in D$ its mean g(a)>g(b), if $g(x) =\ln x$ so $\ln a >\ln b$ for a>b

Comment: @ZevChonoles thanks and at the next time I will do that ^_^

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh, while that's true I'm afraid I don't see how that's relevant. How precisely did you propose to go from $8\ln(\sqrt{8}) > 7 \ln(\sqrt{7})$ to $\ln(\sqrt{8}^{\sqrt{7}}) > \ln(\sqrt{7}^{\sqrt{8}})$ Is it possible that you are confusing $x^{\frac{1}{7}}$ with $x^{\sqrt{7}}$?

Comment: @AWertheim hehehehe because of sleepless but thanks alot

Comment: No problem, glad we could get that straightened out! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your answer, you made the following comment:

> @BarryCipra $8\ln\sqrt8>7\ln\sqrt7$, so $1/7∗1/8∗8\ln\sqrt8>1/7∗1/8∗7\ln\sqrt7$, so $1/7\ln\sqrt8>1/8\ln\sqrt7$ and note that $a\ln b=\ln b^a$.

It is true that:
$$
\dfrac{1}{7}\ln\sqrt8 > \dfrac{1}{8}\ln\sqrt7
$$

However, if you apply the power rule for logs, you instead obtain:
$$
\ln\sqrt[7]{\sqrt8} > \ln\sqrt[8]{\sqrt7}
$$
which is true, but not quite what we wanted.

Comment: thanks and now i understand where is the mistake