# How to prove that $7^{31} > 8^{29}$

Tags: inequality, arithmetic, exponentiation, number-comparison

How can I prove that $7^{31}$ is bigger than $8^{29}$?

I tried to write exponents as multiplication, $2\cdot 15 + 1$, and $2\cdot 14+1$, then to write this inequality as $7^{2\cdot 15}\cdot 7 > 8^{2\cdot 14}\cdot 8$. I also tried to write the right hand side as $\frac{8^{31}}{8^2}$.

Comment: This inequality is equivalent to $31<29 \log_7 8$ or $\frac{31}{29}>\log_7 8$, so if you can find the logarithm and then multiply it by $29$ then you've got it. How to find the logarithm numerically is a substantial question in its own right. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: This fails:$$\left( 1 + \frac{1}{7} \right)^{7\cdot 4 \frac{1}{7}} \leq e^{4 \frac{1}{7}} \geq 7^2$$ Any better ideas?

Comment: I think maybe this problem is from my old problem when Christian Blatter solution a step http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431461/prove-that-sqrt7-sqrt8-sqrt8-sqrt7?lq=1

Comment: Maybe you could try to use the binomial theorem. Note that $7=8-1$ and $8=7+1$.

Comment: I'd love to see a proof using the binomial theorem, but it seems that the two values are two close (relatively) for simple bounds to work.

Comment: @lhf maybe comparing pairwise the terms in the sums or something like that could help... I'll think about it

Answer (score 17):

The following (not particularly elegant) proof uses reasonably basic multiplication and division.

We need to show that $7^{31} > 8^{29}$, i.e. that $\dfrac{7^{31}}{8^{29}}>1$.

We have: $\dfrac{7^{31}}{8^{29}}=\dfrac{7^{2}\cdot7^{29}}{8^{29}}=\dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\Big(\dfrac{7}{8}\Big)^{28}=\dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\Big(\dfrac{7^4}{8^4}\Big)^{7}=\dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\Big(\dfrac{2401}{4096}\Big)^{7} > \dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\Big(\dfrac{2400}{4100}\Big)^{7}=\dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\Big(\dfrac{24}{41}\Big)^{7}=\dfrac{7^{3}}{8}\dfrac{24}{41}\Big(\dfrac{24}{41}\Big)^{6}=\dfrac{3 \cdot 7^{3}}{41}\Big(\dfrac{24^2}{41^2}\Big)^{3}=\dfrac{3 \cdot 7^{3}}{41}\Big(\dfrac{576}{1681}\Big)^{3}>\dfrac{3 \cdot 7^{3}}{41}\Big(\dfrac{576}{1683}\Big)^{3}=\dfrac{3 \cdot 7^{3}}{41}\Big(\dfrac{9 \cdot 64} {9\cdot 187}\Big)^{3}=\dfrac{3 \cdot 7^{3}}{41}\Big(\dfrac{64} {187}\Big)^{3}=\dfrac{2^{18} \cdot 3 \cdot 7^3}{11^3 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 41}=\dfrac{2^{18} \cdot 3 \cdot 7^3}{1331 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 41}>\dfrac{2^{18} \cdot 3 \cdot 7^3}{1332 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 41}=\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7^3}{111 \cdot 17^3 \cdot 41}=\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7^3}{4551 \cdot 17^3}>\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7^3}{4557 \cdot 17^3}=\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7}{93 \cdot 17^3}=\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7}{1581 \cdot 17^2}>\dfrac{2^{16} \cdot 7}{1582 \cdot 17^2}=\dfrac{2^{15}}{113 \cdot 17^2}=\dfrac{2^{15}}{1921 \cdot 17}>\dfrac{2^{15}}{1924 \cdot 17}=\dfrac{2^{13}}{481 \cdot 17}=\dfrac{8192}{ 8177}>1. \quad\square$

Comment: How did you get 7^3/8 * (2500/4100)^7?

Comment: ^^^2400/4100^^^

Comment: It's an inequality.

Comment: $93\cdot 17^3\equiv 1 \pmod 2$ but $1582\cdot 17^2\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Comment: It's now fixed.

Comment: This looks awfully elegant to me!  I like the way you can eyeball each and every step.

Comment: I like this one. Doing it this way might entail some risk, though, as you're depending on not shaving off so much "headroom" with your inequalities that you end up with the ratio less than one. You're left with $0.183$% at the end ($\frac{8192}{8177} - 1$) whereas the amount you started with is about $1.960$%. If you didn't *know* which was bigger, you could end up with a wrong answer, but in this case I think we knew which was bigger, so it's all right ...

Answer (score 9):

Others may bristle at this "proof," but:

$$7^{31} = 157,775,382,034,845,806,615,042,743 \\ 8^{29} = 154,742,504,910,672,534,362,390,528$$

If all else fails, just calculating the expressions and comparing them will work.  This particular problem is only mildly tedious to attack this way if you have pen/paper.

Comment: No need for scare quotes. That's a perfectly valid proof.

Comment: This is in a sense a valid proof, but I can't see how you got the numbers or  why I should believe you got them right. This is a proof, but not an easily human-verifiable one.

Comment: Slightly more readable: $7^{31} =101202171144551276401762715267_8$.

Comment: Not for me... similar situation http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562538/which-is-larger-20-or-240/562543#562543

Comment: And for those of us who once memorized a few logarithms: $\log 7\approx0.84510$, and $\log 8\approx0.90309$. By an easy hand computation $31\cdot0.84510=26.1981$, and $28\cdot0.90309=26.18961$. The difference between $26.1981$ and $26.18961$ is too large to be the result of roundoff error.

Comment: @JpMcCarthy: It clearly *is* a valid proof, and it’s easily (if tediously) checked; claiming otherwise is simply denying the facts.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I know it is a proof... and to be honest I am not sure if there is a proof that doesn't utilise significant computation... where significant is not well-defined in this context.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an idea for a proof that uses some, but hopefully not too much, arithmetic. If you know the power series

$$-\ln(1-x)=x+{1\over2}x^2+{1\over3}x^3+\cdots$$

then you can get started by finagling the desired inequality as follows:

$$\begin{align}
7^{31}\gt8^{29}&\iff31\ln7\gt29\ln8\\
&\iff31\ln(8-1)\gt29\ln8\\
&\iff31\left(\ln8+\ln\left(1-{1\over8} \right) \right)\gt29\ln8\\
&\iff2\ln8\gt-31\ln\left(1-{1\over8} \right)\\
&\iff6\ln\left(1-{1\over2} \right)\gt-31\ln\left(1-{1\over8} \right)\\
&\iff6\left({1\over2}+{1\over8}+{1\over48}+{1\over64}+\cdots \right)\gt31\left({1\over8}+{1\over128}+{1\over1536}+\cdots \right)
\end{align}$$

The final ingredient is to use the inequality

$${1\over n}x^n+{1\over n+1}x^{n+1}+\cdots\lt{1\over n}\left(x^n+x^{n+1}+\cdots \right)={x^n\over n(1-x)}$$

in truncating the infinite sum on the right.  It may take a couple of attempts to find truncations that work.

**Added later** (after seeing math110's answer):  I had quite forgotten my own answer (from two years ago) to the problem of proving [$\sqrt7^\sqrt8\gt\sqrt8^\sqrt7$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431461/prove-that-sqrt7-sqrt8-sqrt8-sqrt7).  In it, I showed all the steps necessary to establish

$$-\ln\left(1-{1\over8} \right)\lt{137\over1024}\quad\text{and}\quad6\ln2\gt{1063\over256}$$

So all that remains here is to note that

$$4\cdot1063=4252\gt4247=31\cdot137$$

Whew!

Comment: It's too complicated for me, but thanks for your anwser.

Comment: You could use $$-31\ln\left(\frac78\right) = 31\ln\left(\frac87\right) = 31\left(\frac17 - \frac1{98} + \dots\right)$$, which is an alternating series and thus easily bounded.

Answer (score 1):

The expression

$$7^{31}>8^{29}$$

Is equivalent to
$$31\ln(7)>28\ln(8)$$
where $\ln$ denotes the natural logarithm. As $7>e$, this is equivalent to
$$\frac{31}{28}>\frac{\ln(8)}{\ln(7)}$$

The above relation can then be easily verified by calculator.

Alternatively, along a similar vein

$$7^{31}=\left(7^{\frac{31}{29}}\right)^{29}$$

As $7^{\frac{31}{29}}\approx8.01>8$ (via my pocket calculator), the inequality follows.

Basically I am still showing this through computation, I'm just trying to make the computations a bit nicer.

Comment: How do you establish your last line?

Comment: Sorry, which line do you mean?

Comment: How do you know $7^{31/29}\approx 8.01$?

Comment: I just used a calculator. I am still proving this by computation, I just tried to make the computations a bit simpler. I'll edit my post to make that clearer.

Comment: John's answer is a much simpler example of using a calculator.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove $(\frac {7}{8})^{29}>\frac {1}{49}$. Write

$(\frac {7}{8})^{29}=(1-\frac 18)^{29}=[1- (\frac 18)^{29}]+\binom {29} {1}[1-(\frac 18)^{28}]+….+\binom {29} {14}[1-(\frac18)^{14}]$

Just the first term in this sum of positive is already greater than $\frac {1}{49}$. 
One has $[1- (\frac 18)^{29}]>\frac {1}{49}\iff 8^{29}-1 > \frac {8^{29}}{49}$ which is quite clear.

Comment: Is this the binomial formula? What's happening in this answer?

Comment: @G Tony Jacobs: Do you doubt that $1-\dfrac{1}{49}\gt (\dfrac 18)^{29}\large?$

Comment: No, I don't. That has nothing to do with my comment. I'm just asking what formula you used here.

Comment: $(a+b)^n=[a^n+b^n]+\binom {n} {1}[a^{n-1}b+ab^{n-1}]+\binom {n} {2}[a^{n-2}b^2+a^2b^{n-2}]….....$

Comment: Oooooooh! I see it now. I'm not used to seeing the terms grouped like that; thank you for clarifying.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, the sum is pretty much all wrong. Apart from the first term, the subsequent ones are missing powers of $(-1/8)$ in the first addend and the signs between the addends should alternate. The terms in the corrected sum are clearly not all positive - in fact, if they were, wouldn't it be strange that $(7/8)^{29}$ is almost equal to $1$ (the first term in the sum) or even much greater than $1$ (second term)?

Answer (score 1):

First, $7^5=16807$ and $2^{14}=16384$. And we have $\dfrac{7^{31}}{8^{29}}=\left(\dfrac{7^5}{2^{14}}\right)^6\times\dfrac78$.

Now, for $x\ge0$ and integer $n\ge0$, we have $(1+x)^n\ge1+nx$, hence

$$\left(\frac{7^5}{2^{14}}\right)^6\ge1+6\left(\frac{7^5}{2^{14}}-1\right)=1+\frac{6\times423}{2^{14}}=1+\frac{3\times423}{2^{13}}=\frac{9461}{8192}$$

Finally,

$$\frac{9461}{8192}\times\frac78=\frac{66227}{65536}>1$$

Therefore,

$$\frac{7^{31}}{8^{29}}>1$$

Comment: It is nice. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

**Lemma.** $5^{15} > 2^{32}\cdot7.$

*Proof.*
The first eight entries in the sixteenth row of Pascal's Triangle
are easily computed recursively by hand (or may be read from a
table). Using them, the Binomial Theorem gives
\begin{gather*}
\frac{5^{15}}{2^{30}} =\left(1 + \frac14\right)^{15} >
\sum_{i=0}^7\frac{\binom{15}i}{4^i}
= 1 + \frac{15}4 + \frac{105}{4^2} + \frac{455}{4^3} +
\frac{1365}{4^4} + \frac{3003}{4^5} + \frac{5005}{4^6} +
\frac{6435}{4^7} \\
= \frac{6435 + 4(5005 + 4(3003 + 4(1365 + 4(455 + 4(105 + 4(15 +
4))))))}{4^7} \\
= \frac{6435+4(5005+4(3003+4(1365+4\cdot1179)))}{4^7}
= \frac{6435+4(5005+4(3003+4\cdot6081))}{4^7} \\
= \frac{6435+4(5005+4\cdot27327)}{4^7}
= \frac{6435+4\cdot114313}{4^7} = \frac{463687}{4^7} > 4\cdot7,
\end{gather*}
because $4^8\cdot7 = 65536\cdot7 = 458752 < 463687.\ \square$

We have $7^4 = 2401 > 2400 = 2^5\cdot3\cdot5^2,$ so
$7^{32} > 2^{40}\cdot3^8\cdot5^{16}.$

But $3^8\cdot5 = 6561\cdot5 = 32805 > 32768 = 2^{15},$ so
$7^{32} > 2^{55}\cdot5^{15}.$

Now the lemma gives $7^{32} > 2^{87}\cdot7,$ whence
$7^{31} > 2^{87} = 8^{29}.\ \square$

Comment: N.B. The mention of Pascal's Triangle was not intended to suggest (as I've just realised with horror it might) that one has to compute the first fifteen rows before computing the sixteenth! What I had in mind was simply the recursion
$$
\binom{n}{i+1} = \binom{n}{i}\cdot\frac{n-i}{i+1}
\quad (i = 0, 1, 2. \ldots, n - 1).
$$

Answer (score -1):

I tried just approximate the numbers and I think I found a very ugly way to prove the inequality. Are there any mistakes?

We have $7^4>24\cdot10^2$ so $7^{31}=7^3\cdot(7^4)^7>7^3\cdot(24\cdot10^2)^7=2^{35} \cdot 3^7 \cdot 5^{14} 
\cdot 7^3$. Also
$8^{29}=2^{87}$. So one has to prove the inequalities $2^{52}<3^7 \cdot 5^{14} \cdot 
7^3=750141\cdot5^{14}<750142\cdot5^{14}$ or $2^{51}<375071\cdot5^{14}<375072\cdot5^{14}$.

This mean we have to 
prove that $2^{51}<2^5 \cdot 3 \cdot 3907\cdot5^{14}$ or 
$2^{46}<3\cdot3907\cdot5^{14}<3\cdot3908\cdot5^{14}=3\cdot2^2\cdot977\cdot5^{14}$ or equivalently
$2^{44}<3\cdot977\cdot5^{14}$. But $3\cdot977\cdot5^{14}<3\cdot976\cdot5^{14}=3\cdot2^4\cdot61\cdot5^{14}$ so 
one has to prove that $2^{40}<3\cdot61\cdot5^{14}$.

But $3\cdot61\cdot5^{14}<3\cdot62\cdot5^{14}$ so one has to 
prove that $2^{40}<3\cdot62\cdot5^{14}$ or $2^{39}<3\cdot31\cdot5^{14}$. But 
$3\cdot31\cdot5^{14}<3\cdot2^5\cdot5^{14}$ so one has to prove that $2^{34}<3\cdot5^{14}$.

Now, lets approximate some square roots:

The inequality above is equivalent to $2^{17}<\sqrt{3}\cdot5^7$. But $\sqrt{3}>1.7$ so one has to prove that $2^{17}<1.7\cdot5^7$. This is the same as $\sqrt{2}\cdot2^8<\sqrt{1.7\cdot5}\cdot5^3$ or $256\cdot\sqrt{2}<\sqrt{8.5}\cdot125$. This is 
the same as $(256/125)^2<8.5/2$ or $256^2\cdot2<8.5\cdot125^2$ or $131072<132812.5$.

Comment: This proof doesn't work.  You proved that $2^{52}<750142\cdot 5^{14}$, which doesn't imply that $2^{52}<750141\cdot 5^{14}$.