# Show by hand : $e^{e^2}>1000\phi$

Tags: inequality, constants, golden-ratio, number-comparison

**Problem:**

> Show by hand without any computer assistance:
> $$e^{e^2}>1000\phi,$$
> where $\phi$ denotes the golden ratio $\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2} \approx 1.618034$.

I come across this limit showing:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x!^{\frac{x!!^{\frac{2}{x!!-1}}}{x!-1}}=e^{e^2}.$$
I cannot show it without knowing some decimals and if so using power series or continued fractions.

It seems challenging and perhaps a tricky calculation is needed.

> If you have no restriction on the method, how to show it with pencil and paper ?

**Some approach:**

We have, using the incomplete gamma function and continued fractions:
$$\int_{e}^{\infty}e^{-e^{-193/139}x^{193/139+2}}dx=\frac{139}{471}\cdot e\cdot\operatorname{Ei}_{332/471}(e^2)>e^{-e^2},$$
where $\operatorname{Ei}$ denotes the exponential integral.

Finding an integral for the golden ratio $\phi$ is needed now.

Following my comment we have :

$$e^{-e^2}<\int_{e}^{\infty}e^{-e^{-193/139}x^{193/139+2}}dx<\int_{e}^{\infty}\frac{e-2}{1000\phi (x-2)^2}dx$$

Where the function in the integral follow the current order for $x\ge e$.As said before use continued fraction of incomplete Gamma function.To finish take the log.

Comment: Title: Can you explicitly state what $\phi$ is?

Comment: That's a pretty tight bound. How did you obtain it from the expression involving factorial?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: It's the "golden ratio" $\varphi = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. The bound is very tight; to two decimal places, it is $1618.18 > 1618.03$.

Comment: @BrianTung I know, and you also know. The OP should write this nevertheless, because $\phi$ is also used as totient function and other things. It would help several other readers, I believe (searching titles).

Comment: FWIW, the smallest-denominator rational number that's in between the two sides is 9709/6 = 1618.1666666...

Comment: Why are there two close votes?

Comment: are you allowed to take $\ln$ from both sides ??

Comment: We have a series as we can get $$1000\phi=e^{e^2}-2e^{-e}-2e^{-2e}-11e^{-3e}-8e^{-4e}-4e^{-5e}-9e^{-6e}-14e^{-7e}-\cdots$$ it's not in eois unfortunately

Comment: @DesmosTutu, where did you find that series?

Comment: @DesmosTutu is there any reason to believe that this is doable by hand? Like, what is the source?

Comment: Little comment, maybe it helps somehow $$\log \phi=\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

Comment: @DS for reference, inequalities with a ratio of less than one in one million have been proven ([example](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4058725/463578)), so this inequality with "only" a one in ten thousand ratio "should be" doable

Comment: Now using $$\int_{e}^{\infty}ea/x^2dx=a$$ the problem is clearly easier. Here all is done with Desmos

Comment: +a translation equal to 2.

Comment: @BrianTung I should have read your comment before I calculated by hand $e > 2.7 \implies e^2 > 7.29 > 7 \implies e^{e^2} > 2.7^7 = 27^7 / 10^7 = 3^{21} / 10^7 \approx 1046$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok, so my answer works but requires you to:

1. Be *insanely* good at arithmetic (so maybe **does not** meet your criteria of *doable by hand*)
2. Know that $\ln 10<\color{red}{2.3026}$ (this might be known to you if you frequently change bases between logarithms, or may be calculated by series expansion)

---

**Edit** (D S) :

I noticed that getting a better approximation for $\ln 10$ significantly reduces the work required for $\ln(\phi)$. So here it goes:
$$\ln(10) = \ln(2)+\ln(5) = 3\ln(2) + \ln(5/4)$$
$$\begin{align}\ln(2) &= \ln((1+1/3)/(1-1/3)) \\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1/3)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
&< 2\left(\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{(1/3)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)+ 2\left(\sum_{k=4}^\infty \frac{(1/3)^{2k+1}}{9}\right) \\
&= 2\left(\sum_{k=0}^3 \frac{(1/3)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)+\frac{(1/3)^9}{4} \\
&= \frac{1910051}{2755620} < 0.693148
\end{align}$$and
$$\begin{align}\ln(5/4) &= \ln((1+1/9)/(1-1/9)) \\
&= 2\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(1/9)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\\
&< 2\left(\sum_{k=0}^2 \frac{(1/9)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)+ 2\left(\sum_{k=3}^\infty \frac{(1/9)^{2k+1}}{7}\right) \\
&= 2\left(\sum_{k=0}^2 \frac{(1/9)^{2k+1}}{2k+1}\right)+ \frac{(1/9)^5}{280} \\
&= \frac{3689393}{16533720}<0.223144
\end{align}$$
Hence $\ln10 < 3\times 0.693148+0.223144 = \color{blue}{2.302588}$.

---

Let $x$ be such that
$$x^{x^2} = 1000\phi$$
or$$x^2\ln(x) = 3\ln(10)+\ln(\phi)$$
We are interested in showing $$3\ln(10)+\ln(\phi)<e^2 \iff 3\ln(10)+\ln(\phi)- e^2<0$$since $x^2\ln(x)$ is increasing in $x$.

---

First, we approximate $\ln(\phi)$. Note that the series expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ for $|x|>1$ is given by
$$\ln(1+x) = \ln(x) - \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{x^{-k}}{k}$$So that
$$2\ln(\phi) = \ln(\phi^2) = \ln(1+\phi) = \ln(\phi) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\phi^{-k}}{k}$$
$$\iff \ln(\phi) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\phi^{-k}}{k}< \sum_{k=1}^{17}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\phi^{-k}}{k}$$since the magnitude of the terms in the sum are decreasing, and we have stopped at a positive term, so this approximation is greater.

Now, to calculate negative powers of $\phi$, you can just extend the Fibonacci sequence backwards, i.e,
$$\ldots \color{blue}{-8,5,-3,2,-1,1},0,1,1,2,3 \ldots$$
For example, $\phi^{-1} = \color{blue}1\cdot \phi \color{blue}{- 1}$, $\phi^{-2} = \color{blue}{-1}\cdot \phi +\color{blue}2$, $\phi ^{-3} = \color{blue}2\cdot \phi \color{blue}{- 3}$ and so on.

In the end, you should get
$$\sum_{k=1}^{17}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\phi^{-k}}{k} = \frac{3433663565\sqrt 5 - 7666113149}{24504480}<\color{red}{0.48123}$$

**Edit:**
With our new approximation of $\ln(10)$, it is enough to take the sum till 13, i.e,
$$\ln(\phi) < \sum_{k=1}^{13}(-1)^{k+1}\frac{\phi^{-k}}{k} = \frac{4109827\sqrt 5- 9120481}{144144} < \color{blue}{0.481266}$$

---

Next, we will approximate $e^2$.
$$e^2 = \left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!}\right)^2>\left(\sum_{k=0}^8\frac{1}{k!}\right)^2$$
(We don't use series expansion of $e^z$ as that requires more terms.)
$$\left(\sum_{k=0}^8\frac{1}{k!}\right)^2 = \left(\frac{109601}{40320}\right)^2>\color{red}{7.38903}$$

---

Finally,
$$\boxed{3\ln(10)+\ln(\phi)- e^2< 3\cdot2.3026 + 0.48123- 7.38903 = 0 \ \ }$$
*Phew!*

**Edit:**
Armed with our new bounds, we have
$$\boxed{3\ln(10)+\ln(\phi) - e^2<3\cdot 2.302588+0.481266-7.38903 = 0}$$

Update DesmosTutu :

We have a trick to evaluate $\ln 10$

$$\operatorname{arcsinh}(10)=\ln(20)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2n-1)!!}{2n(2n)!!(10)^{2n}},\operatorname{arcsinh}(10)\simeq 3$$

Now use expansion of $\operatorname{arcsinh(x)}$ and Engels expansion of $\ln 2$

*Source*: Wikipedia

Comment: Woah, you have high standards for good arithmetic, such as $\frac{3433663565\sqrt 5 - 7666113149}{24504480}<\color{red}{0.48123}$. +1 though.

Comment: @Sahaj I did say "_insanesly_ good arithmetic" :)

Comment: +1. These kinds of questions are always a bit ambiguous on the requirement, but this is certainly doable. People multiply ten digit numbers in their head (I did 4 digits at my best), so this one is routine with pen and paper.

Comment: Answer accepted!!! I open a bounty for you.

Comment: Using the integral in the comment section we have over $(0,1)$ : $$1-\frac{1/2×x^2}{1/2×x^2+1}+1/7×x^4-2/3×x^6×(1-x)^2-1/3×x^8(1-x)^2-1/13x^8(1-x^2)>1/\sqrt{x^2+1}$$ if there is no sign mistake

Comment: @DesmosTutu where are you going with this?

Comment: See comment section calculatormathematical if you speak about the integral and the inequality offering the same rendition as yours

Comment: @DesmosTutu I got a nice approximaltion for $\ln(10)$. Should I remove the old parts, as they make the answer too long? And what about your edit in the end?

Comment: @Sahaj this edit provides some ease of calculation, no? (if you prefer three small calculations than one big calculation)

Comment: @DS let it for the future readers .

Comment: @DS let it for the future readers .

Answer (score 8):

A very small idea which may help someone start towards a solution:

Let $\lambda = e^{e^2}/1000$; we want to show that $\lambda > \phi$. We see directly that

$$e^2 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!} > \sum_{n=0}^4 \frac{2^n}{n!} = 7$$

and

$$e^{7/6} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(7/6)^n}{n!} > \sum_{n=0}^3 \frac{(7/6)^n}{n!} = \frac{4033}{1296} > 3,$$

so

$$e^{e^2} > e^7 > 3^6.$$

Thus,

$$\lambda > 3^6/10^3 > 2/3 > 2/(1+\sqrt{5}) = 1/\phi.$$

The argument up to this point surely can be improved!

Since the roots of $x^2-x-1$ are $\phi$ and $1/\phi$, it now suffices to show that $\lambda^2-\lambda-1 > 0$, i.e. that

$$(e^{e^2})^2 > 10^3 e^{e^2} + 10^6.$$

I'm not sure yet how to do this without a computer, but there is more room between the LHS and RHS here than between $\lambda$ and $\phi$, so hopefully this is a helpful reduction. Basically we are using the fact that $x \mapsto x^2-x-1$ has slope $\approx 2\phi-1 = \sqrt{5} > 2$ near $x = \phi$ to amplify the gap between the two things we want to compare.

Comment: If you look to my approach it should be a sufficient bound maybe.

Answer (score 8):

Although this calculation is long, no special skill, nor even special patience, is required to carry it out entirely by hand.

From [e Continued Fraction --- from Wolfram MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/eContinuedFraction.html),
\begin{multline*}
e > 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{1}{6}}}}}}}} =
2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{6}{7}}}}}}} \\
= 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{4 + \cfrac{7}{13}}}}}}
= 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{13}{59}}}}} \\
= 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{1}{1 +
\cfrac{59}{72}}}}
= 2 + \cfrac{1}{1 + \cfrac{1}{2 + \cfrac{72}{131}}}
= 2 + \cfrac{334}{465} = \cfrac{1264}{465},
\end{multline*}
From $465 \times 271{,}827 = 126{,}399{,}555,$ we get
$$
e > \frac{1264}{465} > 2.71827.
$$
Also, from $738{,}904 \times 465^2 = 184{,}726 \times 8{,}649 \times 100 =
159{,}769{,}517{,}400,$ we get
$$
e^2 > \frac{1264^2}{465^2} = \frac{1597696}{465^2} > 7.38904.
$$
From $22{,}361^2 = 500{,}014{,}321,$ we get $\sqrt5 < 2.2361,$
whence
$$
\phi^2 = \frac{3 + \sqrt5}2 < 2.61805.
$$
Therefore
$$
e-\phi^2 > 2.71827 - 2.61805 = 0.10022 > 0.1002 = 6 \times 0.0167.
$$
From $157 \times 167 = 26{,}219,$ we get
$$
\frac{6\phi^2}{157} < \frac{6 \times2.61805}{157}
< \frac{6 \times2.6219}{157} = 6 \times 0.0167 < e - \phi^2.
$$
Recall the inequality (for a proof, see e.g. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970384/213690) answer, or
[this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2515855/213690)):
$$
e^x < \frac{2 + x}{2 - x} \quad (0 < x < 2).
$$
This gives
$$
\frac{e}{\phi^2} > \frac{163}{157} =
\frac{2 + \tfrac{3}{80}}{2 - \tfrac{3}{80}} > e^{3/80},
$$
whence
$$
\log\left(\frac{e}{\phi^2}\right) > \frac{3}{80},
$$
whence
$$
\log\phi < \frac{77}{160} = 0.48125.
$$
To estimate $\log{10}$ accurately, we need to take an extra term in
the power series used in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4572473/213690) answer, thus:
\begin{gather*}
10 = \frac{65536}{6561}\times\frac{65610}{65536} =
\left(\frac43\right)^8\!\!\times\frac{65573 + 37}{65573 - 37} \\
\therefore\ \log10 = 8\log\left(\frac{1 + 1/7}{1 - 1/7}\right) +
\log\left(\frac{1 + 37/65573}{1 - 37/65573}\right) \\
< 16\left(\frac17 + \frac{1}{3\cdot7^3} +
\frac{1}{5\cdot7^5\cdot(1 - (1/7)^2)}\right) +
2\left(y + \frac{y^3}{3(1 - y^2)}\right),
\end{gather*}
where $y = 37/65573.$
We have:
\begin{multline*}
16\left(\frac17 + \frac{1}{3\cdot7^3} +
\frac{1}{5\cdot7^5\cdot(1 - (1/7)^2)}\right) =
\frac{16}7 + \frac{16}{3\cdot7^3} + \frac1{3\cdot5\cdot7^3} \\ =
\frac{16}7 + \frac{27}{5\cdot7^3} = \frac{3947}{1715},
\end{multline*}
and $y < 1/1000,$ therefore $1 - y^2 > 2/3,$ therefore
$$
2\left(y + \frac{y^3}{3(1 - y^2)}\right) < 2y + y^3 < 2y + 10^{-9}.
$$
Therefore
$$
\log10 < \frac{3947}{1715} + 2y + 10^{-9}.
$$

From $1{,}129 \times 65{,}573 = 74{,}031{,}917,$ we have
$2y < 0.001129,$ whence $2y + 10^{-9} < 2y + 10^{-6} < 0.00113.$
From $1{,}715 \times 230{,}146 = 394{,}700{,}390,$ we have
$$
\frac{3947}{1715} < 2.30146,
$$
whence
$$
\log{10} < 2.30146 + 0.00113 = 2.30259.
$$
Finally,
$$
3\log{10} + \log\phi < 3 \times 2.30259 + \frac{77}{160}
= 6.90777 + 0.48125 = 7.38902 < 7.38904 < e^2,
$$
whence
$$
e^{e^2} > 1000\phi.
$$

Comment: This one wins for me. Excellent answer.

Comment: Alternative proof of the inequality $e^x < \frac{2 + x}{2 - x}$ (corrected version of an earlier comment):
$$
\log\frac{2 + x}{2 - x} = \log\frac{1 + x/2}{1 - x/2} =
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac2{2n+1}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+1} > x
\qquad (0 < x < 2).
$$

Answer (score 4):

$\color{green}{\textbf{Full Solution.}}$

Should be proven the inequality
$$e^2>\ln(1000\varphi),$$
wherein
$$10^{\frac16}<1.4678=\dfrac{1+y}{1-y},\quad 
y=\dfrac {2339}{12339};$$
$$\ln(1000)<18\ln\,\dfrac{1+y}{1-y}<36\left(y+\dfrac13y^3+\dfrac15y^5\dfrac1{1-y^2}\right)<6.907784,$$
$$\,\dfrac{\varphi^2}{e}=\dfrac{\sqrt5+3}{2e}<\dfrac{17393}{18059}=\dfrac{1-z}{1+z},$$
where $z=\dfrac{333}{17726},$
$$2\ln\varphi-1<\ln\,\dfrac{1-z}{1+z}< -2\left(z+\dfrac13z^3+\dfrac15z^5\right)<-0.037576348,$$
and then
$$\ln(1000\varphi)<6.90776427+\dfrac12(1-0.037576348) < 7.3889761<2.71827^2<e^2.$$
Therefore, the given inequality is correct too.

Answer (score 4):

Since $1.6\color{red}{1}81>\phi$, to show $e^{e^2}>1000\phi$ it is enough to show
$$e^2>3\ln10+\ln2+\ln(1-0.19095)$$
We have
$$e^2>(2.71828)^2>7.38904$$
$$6.90776>3\ln10$$
$$0.69315>\ln2.$$
And utilising the fifth degree Maclaurin polynomial of $\ln(1-x)$
$$-0.21188>\ln(1-0.19095).$$
Check: $$7.38904\stackrel{?}{>}6.90776+0.69315-0.21188$$

Comment: What is the source of the constraint $1.681>\phi?$

Comment: https://tr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt%C4%B1n_oran @YuriNegometyanov

Comment: @D.S. Thanks. I did not do it for much attention but challange. Why dont they edit but do jokes when they notice mouse slips? (I am on the phone tough...)

Comment: @BobDobbs Hmm, I usually don't edit posts myself if the poster is an active user. And when you write ```@D.S.``` it doesn't send a notification to me. Instead, ```@DS``` works

Answer (score 3):

Here's a *very* tedious calculation using repeated squaring.  I did use a computer to automate and typeset, but in principle it could be performed by hand.

First:

$$e^z = \left(e^{\frac{z}{2^{m}}}\right)^{2^{m}} $$
and (for $y > 0$)
$$e^y > 1 + y + \frac{y^2}{2}$$
so working with 24 bits after the point (truncating towards zero):

$$\begin{aligned}
e^2 &> \left(1 + \frac{2}{2^{9}} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{2}{2^{9}}\right)^2\right)^{2^{9}} \\
&= \left(1.000000010000000010000000_2\right)^{2^{9}} \\
&\ge \left(1.000000100000001000000001_2\right)^{2^{8}} \\
&\ge \left(1.000001000000100000001010_2\right)^{2^{7}} \\
&\ge \left(1.000010000010000001010100_2\right)^{2^{6}} \\
&\ge \left(1.000100001000001010110001_2\right)^{2^{5}} \\
&\ge \left(1.001000100001010111111010_2\right)^{2^{4}} \\
&\ge \left(1.010010001011010111001100_2\right)^{2^{3}} \\
&\ge \left(1.101001100001001001011011_2\right)^{2^{2}} \\
&\ge \left(10.101101111110000010000101_2\right)^{2^{1}} \\
&\ge \left(111.011000111001010011010111_2\right)^{2^{0}} \\
&= x \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now working with 32 bits after the point:

$$\begin{aligned}
e^{e^2} &> e^x \\
&> \left(1 + \frac{x}{2^{12}} + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x}{2^{12}}\right)^2\right)^{2^{12}} \\
&> \left(1.00000000011101100101010010011001_2\right)^{2^{12}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00000000111011001101111111100100_2\right)^{2^{11}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00000001110110101001101011110101_2\right)^{2^{10}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00000011101110001010010111001100_2\right)^{2^{9}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00000111011111110010010010101001_2\right)^{2^{8}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00001111001101100111110001111000_2\right)^{2^{7}} \\
&\ge \left(1.00011111010101000110011100011110_2\right)^{2^{6}} \\
&\ge \left(1.01000010011111100101101100001001_2\right)^{2^{5}} \\
&\ge \left(1.10010110010000100001101101100000_2\right)^{2^{4}} \\
&\ge \left(10.10000100101101011011111111100110_2\right)^{2^{3}} \\
&\ge \left(110.01010111101000101110111010000110_2\right)^{2^{2}} \\
&\ge \left(101000.00111001101000110101010000011001_2\right)^{2^{1}} \\
&\ge \left(11001010010.00010000000001000110101101110111_2\right)^{2^{0}} \\
&> 11001010010.0001_2 \\
&= 1618 + \frac{1}{16}
\end{aligned}$$

Using the continued fraction convergents as bounds for $\phi$, and long division, get

$$\begin{aligned}
1000 \phi &< 1000 \times \frac{233}{144} \\&= \frac{233000}{144} \\&= 1618 + \frac{1}{18}
\end{aligned}$$

That is,

$$e^{e^2} > 1618 + \frac{1}{16} > 1618 + \frac{1}{18} > 1000 \phi$$

Comment: Although the calculation is long, it is certainly creative (+1)

Answer (score 0):

$\color{brown}{\textbf{What do we prove?}}$

Really, our goal is to prove the inequality
$$\ln(\ln(500\cdot(\sqrt5+1)))<2.$$

We can get the intermediate levels from tables:

$$e^3\approx 20.085\,536\,923\,19,$$
$$e^6\approx 403.428\,793\, 432\,7,$$
$$500\cdot(\sqrt5+1)\approx 1618.033\,988\,75,$$
$$\ln(500(\sqrt5+1))\approx 7.388\,967\,104\,042,$$

But these only look like a magician’s passes, which only distract the audience’s attention from the main process.