# Proof of the following inequality $ \frac{x - y}{\log x - \log y} > \sqrt{xy} $, $x>y$.

Tags: analysis, inequality

I have seen the following inequality 
$$
\frac{x - y}{\log x - \log y} > \sqrt{xy} \ , \quad \forall x>y
$$
be stated as a near "obvious" fact in another [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380302/prove-left-dfrac25-right-frac25-ln2), on the site. 
The inequality is very cute, but so far I have not been able to prove it. 
It reminds me of the Lipschitz inequality, but has some minor differences.
Also Jensens inequality comes to mind. Is there something obvious I am missing, or is this ineqality not as easy to prove as it looks?

Comment: The inequality can be written as $\int_y^x \frac{1}{t}dt < \frac{x-y}{\sqrt{xy}}$. I wonder if one can prove it by comparing areas, and the shape of $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: This seems related to [Logarithmic mean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_mean).

Comment: @N.S. This [demonstration on WA site](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheArithmeticLogarithmicGeometricMeanInequality/) seems to be based on geometric idea. It was the first search result when I googled for [logarithmic geometric mean inequality](https://www.google.com/search?q=logarithmic+geometric+mean+inequality).

Comment: Very nice, that does it!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[image: http://i.imgur.com/t7ipxn0.png]

> Since $1/x$ is concave for $x>0$ then \begin{align*} \log b - \log a = \int_b^a\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} < \underbrace{ \frac{1}{2} \frac{b - a}{\sqrt{ba}} }_\text{Blue Area} +\underbrace{ \frac{1}{2}\frac{b - a}{\sqrt{ba}} }_{\text{Red area}}  = \frac{b - a}{\sqrt{ba}}\end{align*} Implying $$ \hspace{4cm}\sqrt{ab} < \cfrac{b - a}{\log b - \log a} \hspace{4cm} \blacksquare$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint: let $\dfrac{x}{y}=t>1$
and 
$$\Longleftrightarrow f(t)={t-1}-{\ln{t}}\cdot \sqrt{t}$$

and follow is easy to prove it

Comment: Yes, the inequality becomes $(t-1)/\log t>\sqrt{t}$ for $t>1$. A possible simplification is to set $x/y=t^2$, instead, just to get rid of the square root.

Comment: And how does one show the last equality? I proved that they both are zero as $t\to 1$. But showing that the derivative was increasing greater than zero was hard.

Answer (score 2):

Writing $x=t^2y$ with $t\gt1$, the inequality to be proved can be written as

$$t-{1\over t}-2\log t\gt0$$

Letting $f(t)$ be the expression on the left, we see that $f(1)=0$ and

$$f'(t)=1+{1\over t^2}-{2\over t}={(t-1)^2\over t}\gt0 \text{ for }x\gt1$$

This means $f$ is strictly increasing, making it necessarily positive.

Note:  This answer is along the lines of the approaches taken by math110 and egreg.  The main difference was to write the inequality in a way that suggested a function that's easy to differentiate and show is always positive.

Answer (score 2):

Another proof based on geometry is mentioned in 
Frank Burk: *The Geometric, Logarithmic, and Arithmetic Mean Inequality*, The American Mathematical Monthly , Vol. 94, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1987), pp. 527-528, [jstor](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2322844), [link](http://ocw.nctu.edu.tw/course/fourier/supplement/mean%20inequality.pdf). (It was among the first hits in the google search for [logarithmic geometric mean inequality](http://www.google.com/search?q=logarithmic+geometric+mean+inequality).)

We know that function $e^x$ is convex. Let us have a look on this function on the interval $\ln a$, $\ln b$. The line joining the points $(\ln a,a)$ and $(\ln b,b)$ lies above the graph of this function, so we have a trapezoid which contains the whole area lying below the graph. On the other hand, if we make a tangent in the midpoint $(\ln a+\ln b)/2$, we get a trapezoid which lies below the graph of this function. (See the picture in the pdf linked above.)

So we have:
$$\left(e^{\frac{\ln a+\ln b}2}\right) (\ln b-\ln a) \le \int_{\ln a}^{\ln b} e^x \le \frac{e^{\ln a}+e^{\ln b}}2 (\ln b-\ln a)\\
\sqrt{ab} \le \frac{b-a}{\ln b-\ln a} \le \frac{a+b}2
$$

Answer (score 1):

With the substitution $x/y=t^2$, the inequality becomes

$$
\frac{t^2-1}{\log t^2}>t
$$
that, for $t>1$, is equivalent to
$$
t^2-1>2t\log t.
$$

Consider $f(t)=t^2-1-2t\log t$, defined for $t\ge1$; we have $f(1)=0$ and
the derivative is 
$$
f'(t)=2t-2-2\log t.
$$
I claim that $f'(t)>0$ for $t>1$, so the function $f$ is increasing. It's easy to see that $f'(1)=0$ and $\lim_{t\to\infty}f'(t)=\infty$.

Since
$$
f''(t)=2-\frac{2}{t}>0
$$
for $t>1$, the function $f'$ is increasing, so it's everywhere positive (except at $1$).

Of course the proof with convexity is better.

Comment: I think you need $t^2$'s on the left hand side of the first inequality.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Inequality has many demonstrations. Some are made ​​using logarithmic representation with integral. Give here an example:
$$\frac{1}{L( a, b )} = \frac{1}{b - a}\int^{\frac{b}{a}}_{1}\frac{dx}{x}$$
Integrating inequality: 
$$\frac{4}{(x+1)^2}\leq\frac{1}{x}\leq\frac{x+1}{2x\sqrt{x}}$$
is obtained
$$\frac{b-a}{b+a}\leq\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{b}{a} \leq\frac{b-a}{2\sqrt{ab}}$$
hence the inequality in question, but more logarithmic mean framing between the arithmetic mean and geometric mean:$$\sqrt{ab} < \frac{b-a}{\ln b-\ln a}<\frac{a+b}{2}.$$ $(0<a<b)$