# Why is $e^{1/e}$ close to $\frac{13}{9}$?

Tags: exponential-function, approximation

$$e^\frac{1}{e} = \frac{13.002010749 \cdots}{9}$$

Is there a reason why it is close to $\frac{13}{9}$?
Or is this just a mathematical coincidence?

Comment: What does "coincidence" even mean in a context like this?

Comment: Cf.   [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Davis311-320.pdf) by Philip Davis

Comment: Is it also coincidental that $\sqrt{2}$ is close to $\frac{707}{500}$?

Comment: See also the comments for [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724872/why-is-e-pi-pi-so-close-to-20?rq=1), which apply equally here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$13/9$ is a [convergent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Infinite_continued_fractions_and_convergents) of the continued fraction for $e^{1/e}$, so it is expected to be unusually close to $e^{1/e}$.

The continued fraction looks like
$$
e^{1/e} = 1+\frac{1}{\displaystyle 2+\frac{1}{\displaystyle 4+\frac{1}{55+\ddots}}}
$$
and since $55$ is exceptionally large, the approximation
$$
1+\frac{1}{\displaystyle 2+\frac{1}{\displaystyle 4}} = \frac{13}{9}
$$
is exceptionally close.

Answer (score 6):

Although not a ''coincidence'' in the sense that $\frac{13}{9}$ is closely related to the continued fraction expansion of $e^{1/e}$, surprising ''coincidences'' can be generated rather easily. I recommend the following excellent article on the subject:

[Seemingly Remarkable Mathematical Coincidences Are Easy to Generate](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3903/cdce91c73af50b97f24e7825932139867073.pdf)

Comment: Cf. also [this article](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Davis311-320.pdf) by Philip Davis

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you for the link, I will read it

Answer (score 4):

By using the theory of continued fractions, you get a systematic method for generating as many similar "coincidences" as you like. Here's how.

In general, every irrational number $x > 0$ has a *unique* convergent continued fraction expansion of the form
$$x = n_0 + \frac{1}{n_1 + \frac{1}{n_2 + \frac{1}{n_3 + \frac{1}{...}}}}
$$
for unique integers $n_0 \ge 0$ and $n_1,n_2,n_3,\ldots \ge 1$. Truncating this infinite continued fraction to form a sequence of finite continued fractions gives you a sequence of very good rational approximations, starting with
$$x \approx n_0
$$
$$x \approx n_0 + \frac{1}{n_1}
$$
$$x \approx n_0 + \frac{1}{n_1 + \frac{1}{n_2}}
$$
$$x \approx n_0 + \frac{1}{n_1 + \frac{1}{n_2 + \frac{1}{n_3}}}
$$
If a large value of $n_i$ pops up, then the approximation is particularly close when you truncate the expression just before $n_i$.

So, for example, using
$$\pi = 3 + \frac{1}{7 + \frac{1}{15 + \frac{1}{1 + \frac{1}{292 + ...}}}}
$$
if we truncate just before $292$ then we should get a particularly good approximation, namely
$$\pi \approx 3 + \frac{1}{7 + \frac{1}{15 + \frac{1}{1}}} = \frac{355}{113}
$$
which we can compare to the decimal approximation
$$\pi \approx 3.14159265358979... \approx \frac{354.999969856...}{113}
$$
What a coincidence!