# Is it just coincidence that $e + 2\pi$ is very close to 9?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

I was struck by the numerical coincidence
$$
e + 2\pi = 9.0014671356...
$$
which is within 0.02% of 9.

Is this just a coincidence, or can a sensible explanation of this be found, e.g., via a series expansion of some special function that has terms involving both $e$ and $2\pi$?

Comment: Some related-but-difference numerical coincidences: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724872/why-is-e-pi-pi-so-close-to-20 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724872/why-is-e-pi-pi-so-close-to-20 https://xkcd.com/1047/

Comment: Actually, $9.00014671356...$ is not really close to $9$. [This here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4544/why-is-e-pi-sqrt163-almost-an-integer) is really close to an integer, with $262 537 412 640 768 743.99999999999925...$. This has a good reason, but for your case I doubt this.

Comment: I mean, $e$ is a little bit under $3$, $2\pi$ is a little bit over $6$....

Comment: Ah, I see this has already been asked: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1711437/an-integral-for-2-pie-9