# Proof of a particular inequality

Tags: number-theory, inequality

I came up with the following approximation

$$\sqrt[4]{\pi}+\frac{2}{1000}\gtrsim\frac{4}{3}$$

I don't know too much about proving an inequality like this algebraically. I was hoping for an extremely rigorous proof of this (I would definitely appreciate names of theorems). I am *just* starting to self study computational number theory.

I didn't know how to prove this whatsoever. I would think of using a large finite number of iterations on a Taylor series, but I really had no clue how to use that. Thanks for any help.

An similar question type to this is the following: [Prove $\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^{\frac{2}{5}}<\ln{2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380302/prove-left-dfrac25-right-frac25-ln2). My wording is a bit odd in this question, so please note that both questions are very similar. (Solving mine algebraically is really the basis, though)

Comment: Oh yeah, could you please prove assuming you were not given a calculator.

Comment: What do you mean by the symbol $\lesssim$?

Comment: Approximately but still greater than is what that symbol means. You also have it backwards :) @AlexanderDunlap

Comment: [Oh, boy...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19188)

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really by hand, but here is an explanation of what OP found.  We can calculate the [continued fraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) for $\sqrt[4]{\pi}$ as $$[1;3,55,3,1,1,2,3,37,\ldots]$$
We get a good approximation in a continued fraction by stopping just before a "big" number.  Hence we get a quite good estimate as $$\sqrt[4]{\pi}\approx [1;3]=\frac{4}{3}$$
We can refine this by taking more terms:
$$\sqrt[4]{\pi}\approx [1;3,55]=\frac{221}{166}\approx 1.3313253\ldots$$
This explains why $\sqrt[4]{\pi}+0.002$ is close to $\frac{4}{3}$.
To prove the requested bound, we need to go a bit further.  The continued fractions alternate as an overestimate, followed by an underestimate.  $[1;3]$ is an overestimate (for $\sqrt[4]{\pi}$), $[1;3,55]$ is an underestimate, and so on.  Just a few more terms gives us:
$$\sqrt[4]{\pi}>[1;3,55,3,1,1]=\frac{1555}{1168}\approx 1.3313356>\frac{4}{3}-0.002$$
Hence $\sqrt[4]{\pi}+0.002>\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: It looks as if you didn't read the comment below the OPs question (-1)

Comment: Everyone's right. See, I designed this question with the wanting to solve this algebraically. As I didn't specify this very well, I will give a +1

Comment: I have edited the question earlier

Comment: (a) The OP did not include the restriction to hand-calculation in the question itself.  (I don't fault the OP, you understand, it's just an observation.)  (b) This answer states upfront that it is not by hand; it is not misleading.  (c)  It is posted in advance of any answer that *is* by hand.  And (d) it contributes to an understanding of the approximation.  I think it is therefore worthy of a compensatory upvote. +1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is worth mentioning that this follows from the well-known approximation/inequality $\frac{22}{7} > \pi$ because $(4/3)^4 > \frac{22}{7}$.

Comment: This proves that $\sqrt[4]{\pi}<\frac{4}{3}$, which is not what is asked here.