# A double inequality for $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Tags: inequality, approximation, pi, diophantine-approximation

> **Approximating $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from above**

Since
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9\approx 58.220897$$
the root
$$58^\frac{1}{9}\approx 1.5701$$
is not far from 
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\approx 1.570796$$

This approximation may be improved by noticing that
$$0.22\approx \frac{2}{9} = 0.22...\,$$

so 
$$\frac{\pi}{2} \approx \left(58+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{1}{9}\approx 1.570800$$

> **Approximating $\frac{\pi}{2}$ from below**

A similar approximation is given by
$$\left(1+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{9}{4} \approx 1.5707$$
which may be extended to

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \approx \left(1+\frac{2}{9}+\frac{1}{2^3·5^5}\right)^\frac{9}{4} \approx 1.5707963$$
to yield seven correct decimals.

Alternatively,

$$\frac{\pi}{2} \approx \left(58+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{2^4·5^6}\left(1-\frac{13}{3·5^4}\right) \approx 1.57079632679437$$

has twelve correct decimals.

> **Inequalities for $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\log(2)$**

Combining both approximations we may write 
$$\left(58+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{1}{9}-\frac{1}{2^4·5^6}\left(1-\frac{13}{3·5^4}\right)<\frac{\pi}{2}<\left(58+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{1}{9}$$

following the pattern of the double inequality for $\log(2)$
$$\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^\frac{2}{5}<\log(2)<\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\frac{1}{3}$$

taken from a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380302/prove-left-dfrac25-right-frac25-ln2#comment3323115_1593225) to this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/380302/prove-left-dfrac25-right-frac25-ln2).

> **Q** Is  this **58** related to the almost-integer $e^{\sqrt{58}\pi} \approx24591257751.99999982$ ?
>
> (see equation (68) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/j-Function.html))

Comment: I do not mean to be rude or anything, but why would anyone be interested in these ad hoc approximations?  Like if you computed that 
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9\approx 58.220897$$
then isn't it obvious that $58^\frac{1}{9}$ is gonna be an under approximation for $\frac{\pi}2$?

Comment: @BigbearZzz 
It is not so obvious that is that $58+\frac{2}{9}$ is a convergent of $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9$, is it? Maybe I should add that to the question.
Would you consider
$$\pi\approx\left(97+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{110}\right)^\frac{1}{4}$$
an ad hoc approximation?

Comment: I still don't understand. How did you get 
$$\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9\approx 58.220897$$
in the first place?

Comment: It has no hidden steps, it is just an evaluation: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(Pi%2F2)%5E9
I am not sure to understand your question.

Comment: Of course, it is not obvious _a priori_ that $58.222...$ is gonna be an approximation of $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9$, but once you have computed $\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)^9$ using program, it's obvious since
$$58.222...\approx 58.220897$$.

Comment: I can also claim as well that 
$$(\frac65)^{\frac14}\approx \frac{\pi}3
$$
since
$$\left(\frac{\pi}3\right)^4 = 1.20258...
$$
but what's the point here?

Comment: @BigbearZzz You mean that
$$\pi\approx 3\left(1+\frac{1}{5}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\approx 3.13990$$
while the question implies that
$$\pi\approx 2\left(58+\frac{2}{9}\right)^\frac{1}{9}\approx 3.141600$$

Still, if a question started like your comment, I would like to see what comes next.