# Example for Riemann integrable function such that $\int^{a+1}_a f(x)dx=0$ but $ f(x)\neq 0$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm looking for Riemann integrable function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\int^{a+1}_a f(x)dx=0$ for all $a\in\mathbb{R}$,  but $ f(x)\neq 0$.

I suspect that floor function involves here, if so, then how?

Thank you all!

To clarify: $f$ must not be identically equal to $0$, and it should be integrable over any finite interval.

Comment: It would be good if you clarified what you mean by $f(x)\ne0$. Does that mean that $f$ can never take the value $0$? Or rather that $f$ should not be identically equal to $0$? As you see, some of the examples below may or may not work, depending on what you are asking.

Comment: I meant that $f$ should not be identically equal to $0$.

Comment: Then Lana's (user:77181) example works fine, and then the question becomes whether a less "silly" example is possible. Anyway, could you clarify: By "Riemann integrable", do you mean that the improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$ exists, that the improper integral of $|f|$ exists, or that the integrals over finite intervals exist?

Comment: The integrals over finite intervals exist.

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you for the reply. Then the other two examples show a general approach. I would suggest to edit the question so these clarifications are not buried in the comments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about the characteristic function of a singleton?

Comment: How I do that...?

Comment: What is there to do?

Comment: Ok..... got it!

Comment: what is characteristics function of singletons? explain for me please. I do not understand your one line answer.

Comment: Pick $x \in \mathbb{R}$, the characteristic function $ \chi: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ of its singleton $ \{ x \}$ it's defined as follows: $\chi(z):=1$ iff $z=x$, otherwise $\chi(z):=0$.

Answer (score 6):

If you mean "Riemann integrable on every finite interval", try $f(x)=\sin{2\pi x}$. If it needs to be non-zero everywhere, you may redefine it to be $1$ for $2x\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If you want it to be integrable as an improper riemann integral over the whole real axis, simply damp it with $e^{-x^2}$

Comment: @fgp You wont then have $\int_{a}^{a+1}$ to be invariant for all $a$.

Comment: Hm, true. I missed that.

Answer (score 3):

Consider any integrable periodic function with period $1$, which integrates to $0$, i.e., let $g(x)$ be any function defined on interval $[0,1]$. Then consider
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x) - \underbrace{\int_0^1 g(x) dx}_b & \text{if }x\in[0,1]\\ g(\{ x\}) - b & \text{else}\end{cases}$$

Comment: This is surely not improperly Riemann integrable over all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Martin Oh ok. I interpreted the question as Riemann integrable over any unit interval, which I believe is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 1):

How about trigonometric functions?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @vadim123, it sure does... think $\sin x$ between 0 and $2 \pi$.

Comment: @vonbrand,  in my understanding of Math.SE policy short answers like this should be comments instead.  I did not mean to comment on its relevance or usefulness, unfortunately the "low quality post" selection menu inserted this text automatically on my behalf.

Comment: @vadim123, while answers which elaborate are usually desired, in this case being brief is pretty reasonable!

Comment: @vadim123: a [short answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383) that has gotten a fair number of votes.

Comment: @vadim123, I wanted to leave a comment, but the 'Add Comment' button was somehow disabled. I did not comment to critique or request any clarification, but rather to give the OP a hint.