# Calculus III Tricky question! (I think so :) )

Tags: calculus

[image]

Can somebody give me the answer to this one? It is very tricky! I have spent countless hours on this one. I am trying to save myself from doing an all-nighter tonight!

ALso, dont take countless hours the wrong way. It is just a joke/exaggeration. :)

Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Can you share what you've tried during those countless hours, so that people can give help that's not just repeating your work?

Comment: Maybe "you've spent countless hours on this one" means that you've put this homework in front of your computer screen but not looking at it the whole time?  Otherwise show us what you've tried to prove your "countless hours" is genuine

Comment: lol. I use countless as a exaggeration to define how tricky it is. :).  Well first time I tried to use the trapezoid rule. I tried to extend out the peak in some way that would make the answer more accurate but that did not seam to work. Not sure on how I am suppose to do this one.

Comment: I'm certain that you spent a countable number of hours on this problem :)

Comment: HEy whatever! How do you do this question. Officially stuck!

Comment: @CalvinLin Christopher didn't get it. :)

Answer (score 1):

$$\mathbf W$$

${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: This is in clear homage to a previous answer, I think of Didier. As for the second, let us hope you find inspiration

Comment: Aha! Amazingly, searching for W by most votes turns up the [original](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383/9754)