# "Proof" that $0=1$ using an integral.

Tags: calculus, fake-proofs

I saw the following:

$$\begin{align}  \int \tan x \ \mathrm{d}x &= \int \sin x \sec x \ \mathrm{d}x \\  \int \tan x \ \mathrm{d}x &= -\cos x \sec x - \int - \cos x \sec x \tan x \ \mathrm{d}x \\ \int \tan x \ \mathrm{d}x  &= -1 +  \int \tan x \ \mathrm{d}x \\ 0 &= -1   \end{align}$$

I figure the mistake has to do with constants of integration, but I can't quite point it. Can someone explain to me what happens, please? I browsed a bit around here, looking for $0=1$ and the tag `fake-proofs`, but I didn't found it, so I apologize in advance in case this is a duplicate of something (just provide me the link and I'll delete this, no problems).

Thanks!

Comment: Looks good. The results we have proved with great effort now have much simpler proofs.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Note that $\cos x\sec x = 1$

Comment: There is a very similar error in another post here that I can't find, which involves integrating $\sin^2 x$ on one side, and $1-\cos^2 x$ on the other, and coming out with $\frac\pi2 = 0$ as a result.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I would say that the question here is different/specific enough.

Comment: Also [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806375/int-tan-x-dx-by-integration-by-parts)

Comment: Here's another similar one: [$−1=0$ by integration by parts of $\tan(x)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/424854/1-0-by-integration-by-parts-of-tanx)

Comment: I agree that the other suggested duplicates are better.

Comment: @Thomas Up to a sign, this is the special case of $f = \cos$. And for the special case, we have two more duplicates.

Comment: Seeing the answers and comments, it's very clear now. Thanks for the attention. I'll take a look at all these links too (:

Comment: @DanielFischer: I know about the discussion about abstract duplicates. But in general I am opposed to closing questions that aren't "clear" duplicates. I vote to close as a duplicate of one of the other questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, integral equations like this are equal only up to a constant difference.   Therefore you need a + C on one of the sides, and then there is no contradiction, as it is true that $0=-1+C$ for a suitable value of C,  namely $C=1$

Answer (score 3):

You, in fact, have
$$
\int f(x) \; dx = c + \int f(x)\; dx
$$
for any constant $c$. The problem is that you can't subtract the integral on both sides. Remember that the indefinite integral really represents(is) a family of antiderivatives.