# Proof of integration of parts.

Tags: calculus

I can almost see how to derive the formula of integration by parts by this extremely helpful picture: 
[image: integration by parts]

But Im having trouble figuring out how the limits of integration simplify so nicely to how they are, may I please get an explanation on how p,q,s,and r transform into a and b.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is integration by parts, really?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827576/what-is-integration-by-parts-really)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is the opposite, i.e. $a$ and $b$ are transformed into $p,q,r,s$. In a parametric form of a curve, one must have the interval for the parameter to vary. So $x\in [a,b]$ is given
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
u=f(x),\\
v=g(x)
\end{array}
\right.\qquad x\in[a,b].
$$
Then $x=a$ gives the starting point of the curve $[f(a),g(a)]$ which is called for simplicity $[p,r]$ and similar for the final point $x=b$.