# Integrals of inverse functions

Tags: calculus, integration, inverse-function

> The functions $f$ and $g$ are inverse and monotonically increasing. Determine what the following expression is equal to!
> $$
> \int_a^b f(x)\, dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(x)\, dx
> $$

Comment: I would start by sketching a graph and then colouring in what the integrals represent in that picture.

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1115222/42969

Comment: More identical or similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/1115222?lq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is integration by parts. See for example the picture [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827576/what-is-integration-by-parts-really).

Formally you substitute $f(y)=x$ and get
$$\int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(x)\, dx=\int_a^bg(f(y))f'(y)dy=\int_a^b yf'(y)dy$$
hence
$$\int_a^b f(x)\, dx + \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} g(x)\, dx=\int_a^b(x') f(x)\, dx + \int_a^b xf'(x)dx=f(b)b-f(a)a$$
where in the last step we used the integration by parts formula (or the product formula for the derivative).