# A function not differentiable exactly two points of $[0,1]$. construction of such a function is possible?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Can a continuous function on $[0,1]$ be constructed which is not differentiable exactly at two points on $[0,1]$ ?

Comment: A [similar question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/) with the famous *one-letter answer*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider: $$f(x)=\left|x-\frac{1}{2}\right|+\left|x-\frac{1}{3}\right|.$$

Comment: Geometric interpretation of this expression is sum of the distances of a given point on real axis from 1/2 and from 1/3. From this interpretation it is relatively easy to see what the [graph of this function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+|x-1%2F2|%2B|x-1%2F3|) looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Let me give another, potentially more common example: the upper-half circle of radius $1/2$ with center at $1/2$, i.e. $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}$$

Comment: At what two points *exactly* is this function non-differentiable? The only ones I can think of are the extreme points of the definition domain, $\;\left[0\,,\,\frac14\right]\;$ , yet the function is *not* continuous there but only one-sided continuos.

Comment: The function is defined on $[0,1]$, isn't it? The function should be not differentiable in $0$ and $1$. Maybe we need to discuss what differentiability on compact sets means?

Comment: Differentiability, just like continuity, at end points of a closed interval mean both "one sided": right on $\;0\;$ , left on $\;1\;$ . I just thought the OP may have meant something else.

Comment: maybe you are right. However, sclaing my answer to a smaller circle and extending the function by zero will also provide an example with non-differentiability in interior points.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Presuming you allow one-sided limits at interval endpoints in your limit of differentiability (otherwise any otherwise differentiable function is automatically an example because it fails to be differentiable at $0, 1$), you can take as an example the function $f$ defined by $0$ on $[0, \frac{1}{3}]$, $3x - 1$ on $[\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}]$, and $1$ on $[\frac{2}{3}, 1]$. It is nondifferentiable precisely at $\frac{1}{3}, \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: This was my first thought and seemed so simple I assumed there was some implicit prohibition of piecewise defined functions.

Comment: I originally misread the problem asking for a function which was differentiable *only* at two points in $[0, 1]$, which is perhaps more interesting.