# 2×2 matrix with one single eigenvalue, but two linearly independent eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Can we have a  2×2 matrix with one single eigenvalue, but two linearly independent eigenvectors? Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\huge I_{2\times 2}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: (Found my inspiration: [W is an answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/74383#74383))

Comment: That's amazing, and now the torch has been passed on...

Answer (score 0):

If you remember eigendecomposition, you can write a matrix as R*U*R^-1, where R is the matrix of eigen-vectors, and U is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues. Thus you can plug the linearly independent eigenvectors you want into R, as well as the single eigenvalue you want into U.

Comment: You can write a *diagonalizable* matrix in this fashion (but of course this is what the OP wants).