# Name of random variable that's +1 or -1 with equal probability?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Is there a name for this distribution:
$$P(X = 1) = P(X = -1) = 0.5?$$

I'm currently writing $2X-1$ where $X \sim \text{Ber}(0.5)$.

Comment: You can call it “uniform distribution on $\{-1, 1\}$”.

Comment: You can also refer to it as the *sign of* $x$, as in $\frac{x}{|x|} ~: ~a~$ is any positive constant, and $ ~-a \leq x \leq a, ~x\neq 0.$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is the [Rademacher distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher_distribution).

Comment: I am now curious to know what's the shortest accepted answer on Math SE

Comment: @Snoop not accepted, but with many upvotes surely this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/74347/construct-a-function-which-is-continuous-in-1-5-but-not-differentiable-at-2/74383#74383