# How to add a line to a given diagram so that the resulting figure has rotational symmetry but not line symmetry?

Tags: geometry, puzzle

So this is a question I found in the math D book by David Rayner. The diagram is given below.

[image]

> How to add a line to this diagram so that the resulting figure has rotational symmetry but not line symmetry?

I have seen a solution on the internet like this,

[image]

But it doesn't work since the diagram still has line symmetry.
Can anyone suggest me a solution to this? It will be very beneficial.

Comment: Hint: Use a different point as the center for the rotational symmetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$${}{}{}{}{}{}{}\mathsf{N}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/74383/177399

Comment: @MikeEarnest I know that answer personally. I saw the opportunity to take a jibe at it.